# Time and work. Two men and a woman working.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

> Two men and a woman are entrusted with a task. The second man needs
>   three hours more to cope with the job than the second man and the
>   woman would need working together. The first man, working alone, would
>   need as much time as the second man and the woman working together.The
>   first man working alone, would spend eight hours less than double the
>   period of time the second man would spend working alone. How much time
>   would the two men and the woman need to complete the task if they all
>   worked together?

What I have tried:

Let the efficiencies of A,B,C(two man and a woman) be a work/h, b work/h, c work/h.

Therefore:

$$b.(t_1+3)=(a+c)*t_1$$

$$a.t_2=(b+c)t_2$$

$$a.(2t_3-8)=b.t_3$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the efficiencies of the first man be $a$, the second be $b$ and that of the woman, $c$.

It is given that: $$a = b + c \tag{1}$$ $$\frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{b+c} + 3 \tag{2}$$ $$\frac{1}{a}=\frac{2}{b}-8 \tag{3}$$

Solving this, can you get $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$?

Comment: Are you getting 1 h as the answer or 2 h as the answer?

Comment: @Soumee The Answer is 1 hr, right?

Comment: Even I got 1 hour. Book says 2 hr.

Comment: @Soumee No problem, we both got the same answer, so high probability the book is wrong.

Comment: right...Can you show the shortcut method for the question which was duplicate.....

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let us start from another angle.

Let the first man, the second man, the woman individually can do the job in $m_1,m_2,w$ hours respectively.

So, in one hour the first man, the second man, the woman individually can do $1/m_1,1/m_2,1/w$ part respectively of the job  .

So, if the second man & the woman work together all along, in one hour they can do $1/m_1+1/m_2=?$ parts.

So, they will require $\dfrac{m_1+m_2}{m_1m_2}$ hours $\implies m_2-\dfrac{m_1+m_2}{m_1m_2}=3$

Similarly form other equations.

Can you take it from here?