# Shortcut method for time and work questions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

> A tank of 425 litres capacity has been filled with water through two
>   pipes, the first pipe having been opened five hours longer than the
>   second. If the first pipe were open as long as the second, and the
>   second pipe was open as long as the first pipe was open, then the
>   first pipe would deliver half the amount of water delivered by the
>   second pipe; if the two pipes were open simultaneously, the tank would
>   be filled up in 17 hours. How long was the second pipe open?

***I have solved this problem. But I need a shortcut method to solve this problem, the way which people would do in GMAT, CAT or other competitive exams where time is limited.***

Attempt:

$$a(t+5)+bt=425 \tag 1$$

$$2at=b.(t+5) \tag 2$$

$$(a+b)*17=425$$

$$(a+b)=25 \tag 3$$

Solving these I got a quadratic equation:

$$15t^2-205t-300=0$$

$$t=15$$

Possible duplicate: How my question is different: I want a shortcut method to solve the problem. The answer to the previously asked question is not shortcut.

Comment: Too many time & work problems . https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575681/time-and-work-two-men-and-a-woman-working

Comment: @Soumee That is by itself a very short method, right?

Comment: @Rohan Actually one has to solve the quadratic which makes the solution lengthy. In CAT/ Banking coaching classes they teach shortcut methods by which questions get solved in half a minute or so. I wanted to do questions by those methods.

Comment: @Soumee But no quadratic is involved in that linked question!

Comment: @Rohan How did they get y=2x?